# How to count how many sentences are similar?

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataset made by 2 columns, one for users and one for texts:

```
`User`        `Text`
49        there is a cat under the table
21        the sun is hot
431       could you please close the window?
65        there is a cat under the table
21        the sun is hot
53        there is a cat under the table
```

My expected output would be:

```
Text                                   Freq         
there is a cat under the table          3
the sun is hot                          2
could you please close the window?      1
```

My approach is to use `fuzz.partial_ratio` to determine the match (similarity) between all sentences and then groupby to calculate the frequency.

I am using fuzz.partial_ratio so in case of exactly matching, it will return 1(100):

```
check_match =df.apply(lambda row: ((fuzz.partial_ratio(row['Text'], row['Text'])) >= value), axis=1)
```

where value is the threshold. This is to determine matching/similarity

Comment: is this a pandas dataframe ?

Comment: Yes, it is a pandas dataframe

Comment: Where is your code for that approach?  What doesn't work about it?  Stack Overflow is not a coding service; you have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: you say you intend to use `fuzz.partial_ratio` but in your example you have exactly matching values

Comment: Yes, anky. I was considering fuzz.partial_ratio in case I have strings which does not exactly match. In case they match, I should get 1, but in case they do not match I could just set a threshold to group them

Comment: @Prune, I am going to update the question. sorry about that. Since stackoverflow requires a minimal reproducible example, I could not provide it as it is extracted from a code more complex.

Comment: @LucaDiMauro I think you should also edit the example, `fuzzywuzzy` is not justified yet in the example, it is a `value_counts()` (*since the records are exactly matching in the example*) , edit the example to be clear when and why to use `fuzz.ratio` and the expected output accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `value_counts()`

```
df['Text'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.groupby('Text').count()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
from collections import Counter

l=dict(Counter(df.Text))
new_df=pd.DataFrame({'Text':list(d.keys()),'Freq': list(d.values())})
```